# how do you access values in an array with topojson

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm having trouble building a choropleth map and the one thing I'm trying to figure out is how to access an array from a json object:

[image: topojson.feature]

This is what I see in my console for

```
var datum=topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states)
```

and I want to specifically capture the name under properties (eg. State name)

Comment: why not just try features[i].properties.name

Comment: can I create a function like this:    function(i) { return datum.features[i].properties.name;}

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(datum.features[2].properties.name)
```

this should work assuming you want the properties of second object in features array. Also, JSON object is nothing but javascript object you can access the properties like you do in vanilla js